# How to show affine function is translation of linear function?

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis

$f:R^n\rightarrow  R$ , if $\forall x,y \in R^n \text{ and } \lambda \in[0,1]$ 
$$
f(\lambda x+(1-\lambda) y )= \lambda f(x)+(1-\lambda )f(y)
$$
How to show $g(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ is linear ? I try to prove it as define, but fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $f$ is affine you have $$f((1-\lambda-\mu)0+\lambda x+\mu y)=(1-\lambda-\mu)f(0)+\lambda f(x)+\mu f(y).$$ One can rewrite this $$f(\lambda x + \mu y) -f(0) =\lambda (f(x)-f(0)) +\mu (f(y)-f(0)).$$ Hence $g=f-f(0)$ is linear.